# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() - Array

Tags: php, json, array

Bom dia.

Estou tentando consumir um json em PHP porém to tendo esse problema:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\api\consumir\index.php on line 7

Código do Array - JSON

http://jsfiddle.net/svbL9cjb/

Código PHP

```
<?php
$json_file = file_get_contents("http://localhost/api/carne/retornofim.php");

$json_str = json_decode($json_file, true);
$itens = $json_str['nodes'];

foreach ( $itens as $e ) 
{ 
    echo $e['title']."<br>"; 
}
?>
```

http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/34uy-zf37

Att

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\api\consumir\index.php on line 7

Esta mensagem ocorre porque a variável `$itens` não é um array, ou um objeto possível para ser utilizado dentro do foreach, e analisando seu json não existe esta chaves que estão no código (nodes ou title).

Então antes de utilizar o foreach, ou tentar buscar alguma chave coloque:

```
$json_file = file_get_contents("http://localhost/api/carne/retornofim.php");
var_export($json_file);
die();
```

Assim você vai conseguir enxergar o retorno ante de manipular os dados.

Para mostrar mais informações:

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
error_reporting(~0); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$url = 'http://localhost/api/carne/retornofim.php';
$results = file_get_contents($url);
var_dump($http_response_header, $results);
die();
```

Fonte: [PHP: “file_get_contents()” returning NULL from content-verified URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14059923/php-file-get-contents-returning-null-from-content-verified-url)

Comment: agora me retornou NULL

Como faço para puxar os dados do JSON?

Comment: Primeiro você tem que verificar se a url esta funcionando, coloque ela diretamente no navegador http://localhost/api/carne/retornofim.php, se te mostrar o resultado é porque ela esta funcionando.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/j9fv8q

O JSON retorna normal em http://localhost/api/carne/retornofim.php

Agora preciso puxar os dados do JSON para HTML

Comment: Alterei a resposta, você colocou daquela forma, e mesmo assim não esta mostrando nada?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/j9fy38

Me retornou NULL.

Comment: Coloquei um código para você poder debugar o porque que ele não esta chegando.